# How to start gui application on startup in linux ubuntu

Tags: linux, windows, qt, startup, init.d

I have gui application made in Qt and I wont to start it when desktop loads.
I have tried to do this from terminal like this:

```
sudo cp MyApp /etc/init.d
sudo chmode 0777 /etc/init.d/MyApp
sudo update-rc.d MyApp defaults
```

but when I restart computer it gives me program error and asks me if I wont to report it.

Can anyone tell me what could be the problem, and how to solve it?
I should point out that I'm new in linux.

EDIT:

I have also tried to create a script that starts this program, and start this script from startup in the same way but it gave me the same error.

I don't know if it's important but when this application start it starts a thread that reads data from serial port.

Comment: It just shows message box with System program problem detected. Do you want to report problem now, and buttons: cancel and report problems...

Comment: Try to do it with "Startup Application" utility in Ubuntu. Find it here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login

Comment: /etc/init.d is for system services (daemons). UI applications run in a user/non-root session, after logging in. How to auto-start UI applications depends on the environment (KDE, Gnome, XFCE, etc. pp).

Answer (score 3):

You do not start GUI applications in `/usr/include/init.d`. Those are *system daemons* that have nothing to do with GUI. If you want to start an application on start of X session, you have to look at a manpage for Xsession instead.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man5/Xsession.5.html

For example, my ~/.xsession is

```
xkbset r rate 250 25
startfluxbox
```

here `xkbset` is run under my user, as if I started it. It actually has access to DISPLAY and other X resources, something that system daemons **never** do. For system-wide, this is in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d` or whatever your system uses.

Comment: but what if I want to start at GUI at boot time without login?

Answer (score 1):

This solution applies to Ubuntu, for programs startup **after** login

In the activity menu, search `Startup` and find `Startup Applications Preferences`.

[image]

If it's not there, install with

```bash
sudo apt install gnome-startup-applications
```

Then add your program

[image]

Credit: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-autostart-applications-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux